# Cannot RDP after latest Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, firewall

I remote to my home computer when I am at work for various things. Today I ran the scheduled update and now I cannot remote to it unless I turn off the firewall.

Thankfully I also have TeamViewer installed and I was able to remote in that way and verify the firewall is blocking RDP for some reason. Also, once I disabled the firewall and successfully remoted in via RDP, I got the prompt to accept my remote computer's security certificate after entering my credentials. I accepted the certificate a long time ago, so that raised a flag.

I changed the RDP port (security reasons) a while back and verified that the port did not get changed by the update. I checked the firewall settings and they are still allowing the the RDP service to come through the firewall. Some of them are "predefined" and still call out the default RDP port (3389), whereas others (still predefined) allow all ports.

Is there some way to "reset" the RDP configuration or something like that so the firewall knows RDP is OK to let through?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about "resetting" RDP configuration, but I think you would have been better off if you put a rule into your hardware firewall to port-forward the new RDP port to 3389 instead of changing the port that Windows is listening on for RDP. That's a much sturdier implementation in my opinion and I'd guess you wouldn't be having these issues where the port # gets crossed up. MS seems to be updating RDP pretty frequently these days (I use [RDPWrapper](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap) and installed updates last night and it reset things for me as well) so problems are bound to occur.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll check out that RDPWrapper. I am just baffled since I have ran many updates and this is the only that has caused me any grief.

Comment: RDPWrapper allows you to do certain things over RDP that Microsoft doesn't want you to do, such as concurrent logins. I use it on my HTPC so that Movies/Music are always available, but I can login from my laptop and do other things at the same time. If you don't need anything like that, it probably won't simplify things for you.